# How to get the body background color stop applying to divs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Still getting into the whole web dev thing, and I'm not clear on why the background color of my body is being applied to divs on top of it.

I'm using bootstrap from the cdn, and then have these style tags at the top:

```
 <style type="text/css">
            body{
                background-color:Navy;
            }
            .mechBackground {
                background-image: url('homePageBackground.jpg');
                height: 800px;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-position: center;
                background-size: contain;
                text-align: center;
                opacity: 0.4;
                float:center;

            }
            .myText{
                    text-align: center;
                    opacity:1.0;
                    float:center;
            }

        </style>
```

And then:

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron mechBackground" >
        <div class="myText">
            <h1>Some Text</h1>
            <h3>Some more text</h3>
            <br><br>

        </div>
      </div>
```

And my issue is that this changes the background color of everything, including the divs to navy. Instead I'd like just what you can see behind the divs to be navy(so in this case there is a centered div and i'd like it to be navy on the left and right behind the divs), and then the divs just to be not colored at all.

I would think that it would work that way automatically but I guess not?

Comment: divs initial background is transparent, you need to set a color for them.

Comment: Original question is resolved but anyone know why the opacity of 0.4 from the parent div, mechBackground, is also being applied to the child div myText? Even with the 1.0 on it it's still taking the .4 but I'd like it to take the 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default divs have no background colour set, so they are transparent. You need to set a background-color for `mechBackground`.

```
.mechBackground {
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: I see...so for the mechBackground I really just want it to be the image with no coloring at all. I tried making the background-color of mechBackground white but its still tinted.

Comment: Nevermind got it, it was because of the container div on the outside. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

The default background of any div is transparent. If you want the "mytext" div (div I assume you are talking about) to have a different color you are going to have to add a background-color.

```
.mytext{
  background-color: white;
}
```